# PYQT5 - How to change the backgroun color of a checkbox when it is checked, and change it back when unchecked

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I am using checkboxes to make a seating chart for a movie theater and I would like to know how I can change the background of the checkbox when its clicked. I have set a style sheet for its default color but I would like to change it to another one when it gets selected.

The seating chart:

[image: The seating chart]

I have searched around for a while, but have been unable to find a solution.

However, if a method other than using checkboxes is there, I would be open to suggestions. Appreciate it.

```
        regseats = QButtonGroup()
        for i in range(1, 91):
            seat = QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
            regseats.addButton(seat)
            labelm = QLabel(f'A-{i}', self.centralwidget)
            if i <= 30:             
                labelm.setGeometry(QRect(80 + 55 * i, 300, 60, 60))
                seat.setGeometry(QRect(80 + 55 * i, 300, 60, 60))
            elif 30 < i <= 60:
                labelm.setGeometry(QRect(80 + 55 * (i-30), 375, 60, 60))
                seat.setGeometry(QRect(80 + 55 * (i-30), 375, 60, 60))
            elif 60 < i <= 91:
                labelm.setGeometry(QRect(80 + 55 * (i-60), 450, 60, 60))
                seat.setGeometry(QRect(80 + 55 * (i-60), 450, 60, 60))
            seat.raise_()
            seat.setStyleSheet(
                "QCheckBox:indicator:checked:before{width :50px;height : 50px;background-color: rgba(18, 122, 137, 0.4)}")
```

Comment: Just add another rule without the `:checked` selector. Note that QSS don't support the full CSS syntax, they're only *based* on it (and only with the 2.1 implementation): there is no `:before`.

Comment: ```vseat.setStyleSheet(
    "QCheckBox:indicator:checked{width :50px;height : 50px;background-color: rgba(128, 22, 137, 0.4)};QCheckBox::indicator{width :50px;height : 50px;background-color: rgba(0, 22, 137, 0.4)}")```
do you mean like this?

Comment: Yes, conceptually, but you made mistakes there: 1. the semicolon is only to separate properties, not selectors (remove it before the second `CheckBox` selector); 2. QSS [color type](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#color) only accepts integers between 0-255 and percentages, so the alpha is invalid and should be `40%`.

Comment: Note: there's no point in setting the same stylesheet to multiple widgets, you just need to use correct [selector types](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) and set the stylesheet for the common parent, the window or even the whole application (you can even create fake subclasses and use the type selector with their names). Finally, after seeing your screenshot, it seems that you're not actually using a QCheckBox as normally intended, so it's quite pointless: just use a standard button (so you don't need a label), make it checkable, and use the pseudo states as above.

Comment: Another thing: it seems like the seats are placed in a grid. Except for some very special cases, you should always use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) and avoid explicit, fixed geometries. In your case, use a QGridLayout (and eventually set spacings and stretches accordingly).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use the QPushButton with the checkable property set to True, rather than tweaking with the QCheckBox and QLabel.
You can do like this.

```
b = QPushButton('A-1', checkable = True)
b.setStyleSheet('''
    QPushButton {
        width:50px; height:50px;
        border: none;
        background-color: green;
    }
    QPushButton:checked {
        background-color: red;
    }
''')
```

If you insist using the QCheckbox, do like this at least for the box.

```
c = QCheckBox('')
c.setStyleSheet('''         
    QCheckBox:indicator {
        width:50px; height:50px;
        background-color: green;
    }
    QCheckBox:indicator:checked {
        background-color: red;
    }
''')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I switched over to the buttons. Its much easier to handle!